# Cannot find "Attach to Process" option in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, iis

Is this option "Attach to Process" not available in express edition? I tried to find the option under TOOLS -> customize and TOOLS -> Options but not luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should check with

Debug >> Attach to process

[image]

Comment: It is not available there.

Answer (score 0):

VS Express 2012 for Web doesn't have it, I have the same Environment as yours, it really has no this feature, but as far as I know, the VS 2012/2013 Express for Desktop would support this feature. Of course, if possible, I suggest you use the higher VS version like the VS2013 or VS2015 community version which is also free and has more features.

[image]

Comment: @NoobTechie, would you please use other VS version if you have to use the Attach to process feature? Please feel free to share the latest information about this issue?